# Web Developer Novice: How To SSL + Digital Ocean + Bitbucket

Tags: ssl, digital-ocean

Rookie web developer, 1 year in the business, I know enough to know I don't know a lot.

I am maintaining/updating a site designed by someone else. The immediate need is to set up SSL on the site. Original dev used Let's Encrypt, but it has expired and I don't know how to update.

Original dev gave me a lot of access/login info that I cannot decipher.

It looks like it is hosted by Digital Ocean, as he gave me a droplet name, along with IP address, username and password--but these do not log me in to any account on digitalocean.com.

He also gave me some CLI prompts, though I am not very familiar with CLI.

And I have access to the Bitbucket repo, but I do not know if I can install SSL from this.

I welcome any help in connecting these dots.

Comment: To renew / reissue the Let's Encrypt certificate with domain validation you will need to log into the server to change files that the web server hosts. You can possibly do this manually if you have FTP access? But if it's set up already then there should just be scripts on the server to run (and that's by far the easiest way). You'll have to solve the issue of how to log in, and I suggest you contact the original developer if you can for help understanding the credentials he's left you or try Digital Ocean support too.

Comment: Alternatively Let's Encrypt supports DNS validation if you have control of the DNS servers for the domain? (Or access to a web console at your host that will let you add TXT or CNAME records?) But unless you have a CI server or similar that will deploy an updated version for you then code and bitbucket access won't help sorry, and may not even if you do.

Comment: The credentials given to you by the previous guy are server (droplet) specific, they will not work for logging into DO's control panel as they are intended to be used when connecting via SSH/CLI to the droplet.

Comment: That said, You can automate the process of renewing the Let'sEncrypt certs with just a little bit of CLI tinkering to install a couple of things in the droplet. It literally takes less than 10 minutes (and that's including the configuration changes on your webserver, if required) following a DO tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The login credentials supplied to you are droplet-specific and intended to be used to SSH into the droplet (using putty or other terminal emulator).

That said, you may automate the Let'sEncrypt cert renewal by installing Certbot on your machine. It requires a bit of CLI tinkering on the droplet (and sudo privileges) but a tutorial like this takes literally less than 10 minutes to complete even for the uninitiated. Check:
[Secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)

If you're not using Nginx, or your OS is something other than Ubuntu 16.04, you may find other tutorials on DO's website

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. As I understand it, I need to install nginx (is this a paid tool?) on the IP address where the site lives, and then install Certbot, and can then manage SSL after that? (I am on macOS)

Previous dev gave me this: `rsync -avzr --exclude='.git/*' -e 'ssh' ./ <username hidden>@<IP address hidden>:/var/www/html` What does that do?